# How to write functional test about page content?

Tags: django, functional-testing

I'm new to functional testing (i'm using Django + Selenium) and all examples show user stories such as the following : "An anonymous user wants to log in, she clicks on "log in" button, enters her credentials and notices that she's now logged in".

My question is how to test stories about "passive" interaction. For example, imagine a website where users can post three different kind of content : Content A, content B, content C. The landing page is the user's newsfeed (à la facebook). Since an anonymous user has no newsfeed yet, we want to **test that she can sees a "default" newsfeed with the three types of content**, so it's not just about testing user input steps.

Does it make sense to test this with a functional test ? I'm using a TDD approach so how can I test this without injecting too much database dependencies for example ?

Answer (score 0):

I think this is definitely a functional test. I would suggest to prepare 3 different pages with the different URIs. Each page will contain different content A, B or C. Also each type of the content should has some specific element/class that not presents in other content (lets call it - content ID). Then you will build the test that going to 3 content pages and looking for the specific content ID. Test will pass if all 3 content IDs will be find.